# Law of large numbers for arrays

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I want to show that:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{i,n}\overset{p}{\to}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE(Y_{i,n})
$$
Given that $Y_{i,n}$ are independent across $i$, for any given $n$. There might be some other conditions missing, which I also have to figure out.
I know Kolmogorov's SLLN.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: The second index is constant here, you can ignore it.  Just define $Z_i=Y_{i,n}$ and proceed.

Comment: @RossMillikan In the example that I have $Y_{i,n}=\sigma^2(i/n)X_i$. Doesn't $n$ matter here?

Comment: So your $n$ on the left is also going to infinity.  I missed that.

Comment: @RossMillikan is there a better way to write it?